# Maven sub modules depending on each other

Tags: java, maven, testing

Currently I have a single module which has both integration tests and unit tests. I'm trying to split this into 2 projects, so unit tests remain in the main code base, and a separate module for the integration tests.

Therefore, I have created a new sub module (module B), which depends on the first sub module (module A) so the integration tests have access to the src code.

The problem I have is that both the unit tests and the integration tests use some util assertion classes (e.g. custom hamcrest assertions). These util assertions should not live in the src code of module A, but I dont believe they should be in module A test directory either.

Therefore it is pointing to another project for all these custom assertions. This is then very messy... Does anyone know of a way round this?

My thoughts were to have module B to have the src directory containing all the custom assertion classes which can be imported as a dependency into module A (but this causes a cyclic dependency error).

Comment: My 2¢: a third module for custom assertions sounds exactly right

Comment: Why do you want to put the integration tests into a seperate module? Do you know the Maven way of handling integration tests: [Maven Failsafe Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/). By using a different name pattern (*IT.java) for your integration tests they are cleanly separated from your unit tests (*Test.java) - and also executed separately. If you are aware of this and want/need module separation 3rd module is a good option for your common classes.

Comment: A separate module with integration tests can make sense if you need having different classpath during your integration test than in your unit tests which is often the case. But of course using the naming convention is a good idea in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about things getting messy. This is the enemy of maintainability.

What I do is I maintain the custom hamcrest assertions and matchers in `src/test/java` in module A and then add a secondary execution of the maven-jar-plugin to create a `test-jar` artifact:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>au/com/mycompany/serialization/**.class</include>
                            <include>**/AddressMatcher.class</include>
                            <include>**/AddressAssertion.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This jar is then added as a dependency in module B:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.mycompany.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

You minimise complexity this way and improve maintainability.